# JavaScript self invoking function closure not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

Disclaimer: I'm trying to use closures as I have been told they are a good practise (and I understand that – not having variables get used in other functions etc) but I don't 100% understand what I'm doing! 99% of the time they work great.

I have the following function:

```
(function(){
    $("#job-titles-list a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```

But when I click any of the links, I am taken to their `href`. If i change the function to:

```
// (function(){
    $("#job-titles-list a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
// });
```

My question is how can I make the closure work / should I not be using closures to do what I'm doing?

(I know I don't need both `return false` and `e.preventDefault()` but I was trying a couple of things when it wasn't working)

Comment: `(function() { ... })();`?

Comment: Unrelated, but there's zero reason to use closures or a self-executing function here. It's only useful if you actually need to encapsulate something, which in this case, you don't.

Comment: @Satpal Any time you create a function you're creating a closure--it's just not necessary in the example code given.

Comment: Doh. Its been a long day. nb it is a much longer function, I just reduced it to show the core bits that weren't working. Clearly didn't reduce it enough to notice the lack of brackets! Luckily now there are answers I can't delete the question so will have to live with this embarrassment forever... or change my username, move house, start over...

Comment: closure, not en_closure, is the technical term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define a function expression but you don't call it. Add parenthesis :

```
(function(){
    $("#job-titles-list a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
})();
```

Note that if you don't have more code inside the [IIFE](http://benalman.com/news/2010/11/immediately-invoked-function-expression/), it's totally useless as you're not adding any variable.

Comment: alternatively, add `$` at the beginning, to be sure that DOM is ready.

Answer (score 1):

You defined the enclosure, but have not called it:

```
(function(){
    $("#job-titles-list a").click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
})(); // < -- Note the () here.
```